# Can I drive only one MOSFET/IGBT in a DC chopper circuit using IR2112 driver?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, mosfet-driver, three-phase, igbt

I have a three phase inverter that is driven with 3 IR2112 drivers board and microcontroller.

I want to take advantage of the board and take two wires from these drivers pins to trigger one MOSFET/IGBT.

Which pins should they be?

[image]

Comment: The IR2112 is a half-bridge driver with (typically) a bootstrapped high side drive.  From your question it's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to use the driver board to hook up to other FETs?  What configuration?  You should add a schematic of how you think things would be hooked up.

Comment: Note the high-side outputs on the gate driver IC will not work without a corresponding low-side switch. THis is because the bootstrap capacitor that provides a floating supply for the high-side MOSFET drains and needs to periodically refreshed and does so when the low-side MOSFET conducts (which it must do periodically, usually part of normal operation). So you probably cannot use the high-side on its own. If you aren't PWMing at high frequency you don't need to use a gate driver at all. Just drive the gate directly.

Comment: I think the arduino PWM is not capable of driving the FETs I have "BUK455, or IRF740".

Comment: the idea is just taking pulling two wires from the driver board one to the gate and one to the source so I can trigger a single one MOSFET/IGBT in a DC chopper circuit (converter)